# kendo grid with foreign key without relations in database design

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a database without the relations between tables in SQL Server, but the data are relationated.

I am trying to use a Kendo Grid with Foreign Key column, but, the example that I found is for database with correctly related tables.

How I can declare a Kendo Grid when for a Foreign Key column I said who is the Action and Controller to fill this data.

Comment: Do you have an entity or object model?  Are you using some sort of ORM?

Comment: I am using Entity Framework.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if your database has the FKs or not.  It's more important that your objects are linked together through navigational properties.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you may do like this:

Let's say we create a foreign key column about gender

```
col.ForeignKey(m => m.id_gender, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["gender"], "id_gender", "description");
```

In the controller, we may create a ienumerable collection then pass it back to the view using view data

```
IEnumerable<GenderItem> gender_list = .... <-- initiallize the ienumerable or get from database
ViewData["gender"] = gender_list;
```